# Remove fixed server role 'SECURITYADMIN' for SPFARM user

Tags: 2013, permissions

Hi by default spfarm user has below permissions refer to  TechNet article

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/account-permissions-and-security-settings-in-sharepoint-2013

Dbcreator fixed server role.

Securityadmin fixed server role.

db_owner for all SharePoint databases.

can we remove fixed server role 'SECURITYADMIN' for SPFARM user and after removing this role is SharePoint and web applications will work?

this is due to company dba team has some restriction on this role

Answer (score 0):

**dba team has some restriction on this role**

The BDA admin has logic reasons to remove `securityadmin` server role from the `SPfarm account`, because from DBA preselective:

- Members of the `securityadmin` fixed server role can GRANT, DENY, and REVOKE server-level permissions.
- They can also GRANT, DENY, and REVOKE database-level permissions if they have access to a database. Additionally, they can reset passwords for SQL Server logins.

> The securityadmin role should be treated as equivalent to the sysadmin role.

**Remove fixed server role 'SECURITYADMIN' for SPFARM user, is SharePoint and web applications will work?**

**Sure,** it's not recommended, but it will work!!!!

**But keep in mind:** you will **not be able** to

- Run the configuration wizards correctly.
- Run PowerShell cmdlets that requires security access on the server level for SharePoint database.
- Perform configuration tasks like, Configure Services ...etc via CA or PS that requires security access.